# node.js in a dockerfile cant connect to mongolabs via mongoose: getaddrinfo ESRCH

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have done some googling but haven't found anything..

My setup is like this:
OS X, boot2docker, everything local except mongolabs database.

The project is working fine when it's not inside docker.

I am trying to run my nodejs project inside a docker image. I have done this before, but not with a database connection requirement. The problem is that my node app crashes on startup with the information:

```
/src/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                                ^
    Error: getaddrinfo ESRCH
        at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
        at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Is there a DNS flag inside docker that can be set or is anything blocking my connection to the outside?

EDIT:

I connect to my mongodb on mongolabs through mongoose.

```
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');    
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
```

and my passport.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds045027.mongolab.com:45027/database

};
```

Comment: Yes, I will update the question

Comment: Updated question again :)

Comment: Have you checked what the iptables config is inside your boot2docker install? Unsure if it will be that, but possible that it is blocking outgoing connections I suppose...

Comment: The outgoing connections is not the problem, I can reach outside from other dockerfiles